# How to sum numbers according to their sign in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to sum numbers according to their sign in SQLite. I can write two separate commands:

```
SELECT sum(x) FROM table WHERE x >= 0;
SELECT sum(x) FROM table WHERE x < 0;
```

Is there a way to combine it into one command? Two separate commands seem to be inefficient (as we are checking conditions twice).

Comment: this should be `x >= 0` rather than `x =>0`

Comment: @marmeladze Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a conditional SUM

```
SELECT sum(case when x > 0 then x else 0 end) as positives,
       sum(case when x < 0 then x else 0 end) as negatives
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Normally you can expect an answer on Stack Overflow in the first 5 minutes.